# ffmpeg - replace the Center channel on a 5.1 AC3 without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, ac3

Is it possible replacing the Center channel on a 5.1 AC3 without re-encoding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done.

AC3 5.1 is encoded into a stereo format; the separation is done at decode. So there's no 'centre channel' to remove from the 5.1 file without decoding it first.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, but I wrote AC3, not AAC :)
I'm trying with something like this:
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex '[0:a:1]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side):channels=FL[FL];[0:a:1]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side):channels=FR[FR];[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=mono:channels=FC[FC0];[0:a:1]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side):channels=LFE[LFE];[0:a:1]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side):channels=SL[SL];[0:a:1]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side):channels=SR[SR]' -channelmap [FL]|[FR]|[FC0]|[LFE]|[SL]|[SR]:5.1(side) output.ac3
without lucky :(

Comment: Sorry, typo Doesn't change the fact that you have to decode it, then of course re-encode it with the new centre channel.

Comment: So, it's not possible replace only a single channel of a 5.1 AC3 without re-encoding all channels..

Comment: …just as the opening sentence of my answer already says…

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: The resulting file is not stereo audio. Dolby Digital is not Dolby Surround. It has some similarities however: Discrete channels can be linked in various ways to improve compression.

Comment: @DanielB - let's call it 'stereo with metadata'. I actually process it for my HTPC through stereo compressors before decoding in an external AVR. Because the computer itself does not contain the ability to decode into 6 discrete channels, I cannot run it through my 5.1-capable comps which I use to *make* soundtrack cues. They can only find 2 channels. [BTW, I am no expert in codecs by a long way, but I am a professional sound engineer;) See https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/45949/mac-pro-3-1-true-5-1-control-over-outputs